# What does ぐいつ mean?

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, word-usage

[image]
Can somebody help me, please?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That doesn't actually say ぐしう, it says ぐいっ. It conveys the idea of a sudden, sharp movement that is vigorous or strenuous.